# Column equal to a results of function which takes as inputs parameters from other columns R

Tags: r, function, datatable

this is an image for my data table :
[the data table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZtip.png)
[Data Link](https://easyupload.io/0bc5e6)

So i want to fill the last column using a function which takes as input other columns values. i prepared the function but it doesn't work correctly because for states it take just the cell value but for the others it takes the whole column values.

```
 for (i in rev(seq_len(52))) { # rep(52:1, times = nb_cycle)
    watervalues[
      weeks == i,
      value_node := calculate_Bellman_value(
        watervalues$states , states_next = watervalues$states_next, value_reward = watervalues$reward,
        value_inflow = watervalues$hydroStorage, decision_space = decision_space, level_high = watervalues$level_high,
        level_low = watervalues$level_low, value_node_next_week = value_node_next_week, niveau_max = niveau_max, E_max = max_hydro,
        method = method, na_rm = na_rm
      ),
      by = list(years, statesid)
    ]
```

calculate_Bellman_value() take the actual states and identifies the all possible transition can be made using the level low level high and hysroStorage then it use the Bellman equation to calculate the optimal value for each state in each time. this value is used to fill the column value_node in the data.
this is the function:`

```
calculate_Bellman_value <- function(states, states_next, value_reward, value_inflow, decision_space,
                                 level_high, level_low, value_node_next_week, niveau_max = 10, E_max = 1.344, method, na_rm = FALSE) {

  value_reward <- unlist(value_reward, use.names = FALSE)
  decision_space <- unlist(decision_space, use.names = FALSE)
  states_next <- unlist(states_next, use.names = FALSE)
  alpha <- getOption(x = "antaresWaterValues.alpha", default = 0.0001)
  decimals <- getOption(x = "antaresWaterValues.decimals", default = 3)


  #eliminate non accessible states
  if (states >= round(level_high, decimals) - alpha) {
    return (-Inf)
  }
  if (states <= round(level_low, decimals) + alpha) {
    return (-Inf)
  }


  # max possible decision --------
  largest_decision <- min(c(states + value_inflow, E_max), na.rm = TRUE)
  largest_decision <- round(largest_decision, decimals) ###

  # the decisions that respect the max possible decision used in simulation constraints
  decisions_current_benef <- decision_space[decision_space <= largest_decision + alpha]
  decisions_current_benef <- round(decisions_current_benef, decimals) ###


  # List of accessible Rewards
  provisional_steps <- unique(c(decisions_current_benef, E_max) )
  provisional_reward_line <- unique(c(value_reward[seq_along(decisions_current_benef)] , value_reward[length(value_reward)]))

  # Possible next states
  next_states <- states_next[states_next >= (states - E_max + value_inflow) & states_next <= (states + value_inflow + alpha) ]

  # Turbaned energy per transition
  decisions_benef_to_go <- states - next_states + value_inflow
  decisions_benef_to_go <- round(decisions_benef_to_go, decimals) ###


  decisions <- unique(sort(c(decisions_benef_to_go, decisions_current_benef), decreasing = FALSE))


  if (length(setdiff(decisions_benef_to_go, decisions_current_benef)) > 0) {

    # boucle sur les quantité de turbinaga possible
    for (index in setdiff(decisions_benef_to_go, decisions_current_benef)) { # index <- 70000 MWh

      # Closest inf simulation constraint
      before <- provisional_steps[index >= provisional_steps - alpha]
      before <- before[length(before)]

      # Closest sup simulation constraint

      after <- provisional_steps[index <= provisional_steps + alpha]
      after <- after[1]

      # For interpolation
      remainder <- (index -  before ) / (after - before)
      remainder <- round(remainder, decimals) ###
      remainder <- abs(remainder - trunc(remainder))

      # index_before <- match(before, provisional_steps)
      index_before <- which(num_equal(before, provisional_steps))
      index_before <- round(index_before)
      # index_after <- match(after, provisional_steps)
      index_after <- which(num_equal(after, provisional_steps))
      index_after <- round(index_after)

      # calculate interpolated reward
      interpolation_current_benef <- provisional_reward_line[index_before]*(1-remainder) + provisional_reward_line[index_after]*remainder


      provisional_steps <- unique(sort(c(index, provisional_steps), decreasing = FALSE))

      new_reward_element <- interpolation_current_benef


      # add the reward to the list keeping the increasing order of turbaned energy
      provisional_reward_line <- c(provisional_reward_line[seq_len(index_before)],
                                   new_reward_element, provisional_reward_line[index_after:length(provisional_reward_line)])

    } # fin boucle sur  sur les quantité de turbinage possible

  } # fin if


  # respect the guide graph constraints
  decisions <- decisions[decisions - alpha <= states + value_inflow - level_low]

  decisions <- decisions[decisions + alpha >= states + value_inflow - level_high]

  decisions <- round(decisions, decimals) ###


  # initialize
  temp <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(decisions))
  count_x <- 0



  for (l in decisions) { # l <- 0

    count_x <- count_x + 1


    # Respect Reservoir Capacity
    if ((states - l + value_inflow) >= niveau_max + alpha) {
      next
    }


    states_above <- states_next[states_next >= (states - l + value_inflow) - alpha]
    states_below <- states_next[states_next <= (states - l + value_inflow) + alpha]

    next_node_up <- which(num_equal(states_above[length(states_above)], states_next))
    next_node_down <- which(num_equal(states_below[1], states_next))

    remainder <- 0

    if (!num_equal(next_node_up, next_node_down)) {
      remainder <- (states - l + value_inflow) / (states_above[length(states_above)] - states_below[1])
    } else {
      remainder <- 0
    }

    # Bellman value of the next week
    vunw <- value_node_next_week[next_node_up]
    # if (!is.finite(vunw))
    vdnw <- value_node_next_week[next_node_down]
    interpolation <- remainder * vunw + (1 - remainder) * vdnw


    temp[count_x] <- sum(c(provisional_reward_line[num_equal(l, provisional_steps)], interpolation), na.rm = na_rm)
  }


  if (method == "mean-grid") {
    return(max(temp, na.rm = TRUE))
  } else {
    return(mean_finite(temp))
  }
```

you can check the used Dataset [Here](https://easyupload.io/0bc5e6)
Thank you !

Comment: Please provide your data table with code,  try to run `dput(dt)` and copy it in your question.

Comment: @peacewang i tried to put as much as i can

Comment: You had better to explain how to fill the last column,  the function `calculate_Bellman_value` maybe can avoided. (A minimum data set is weclome)

Comment: Sorry. But I am still not very clear what's your  specific problem and what's your  specific desired result ( for benchmark). If  the  `calculate_Bellman_value() ` is not complicated, can you show its definition? Otherwise, I don't undertand this `because for states it take just the cell value but for the others it takes the whole column values`. (Still : A minimum data set is weclome, just use several rows to show your question and your desired result)

Comment: @PeaceWang  I put the data set link in the question you can check it via the link.

Comment: @PeaceWang i added the function Code and the full Dataset in the question. Thank you !

Comment: Oh, the definition of `calculate_Bellman_value` is really a little bit complicated for me. Can you  try to  use  some simple data to reach your question directly ( if possible)?  I guess this `because for states it take just the cell value but for the others it takes the whole column values` is the point? Try to show it with a simple data (I guess 4 columns is enough). Best regard.